# a php error on server about the version

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have an error in my server which belongs to the security.
is there anyone know how to solve it?

system: Linux CentOS

```
--------------------
 YUM - security
 --------------------
Error: Package: php-pecl-xdebug-2.1.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php-common >= 5.3.3-38
           Installed: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 (@sl-security)
               php-common = 5.3.3-27.el6_5.1
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (sl)
               php-common = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (sl-security)
               php-common = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Everything is in the error message, `Requires: php-common >= 5.3.3-38` & `Installed: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64` maybe you should upgrade your php version

Comment: @teeyo I am afraid if I upgrade it, it will mess up with whatever I have in the system. can you tell me how to upgrade it or how to ignore the error?

Comment: That's exactly why I use vagrant for my development, it completely separates your machine from development environment, take a look at https://www.vagrantup.com/ and you'll probably need the homestead for the PHP development https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead